# What is the Minzinc path for Python?

Tags: python, minizinc

I'm trying to run a Python script on Windows using the Python minizinc module.

Since My Minizinc is not installed in the default folder, I'm trying to define a new driver, but I don't know what I need to use.

Do I need to use `find_driver()` linking to a certain file or folder, and if so which one?

I tried with D:\Minizinc, D:\MiniZinc\minizinc.exe and D:\MiniZinc\bin without any success.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't find MiniZinc driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67417208/cant-find-minizinc-driver)

Comment: The path should include the directory that includes the `minizinc.exe` file

Comment: No I does not really answer my question because the path is not explicit, and I would like to have a concrete exemple.

Comment: So then if  I understand correctly my minizinc.exe is in D:\MiniZinc this should be the path ? It does not work for me

Comment: That should work. Did you use the correct type for the arguments of `find_driver`? It needs a list of strings, if you just pass it a single string, then it might use each character as a path.

Comment: Thank you that was the issue, I had to put my path in a list. For the record, I all my imports writen at the beginning worked perfectly except for `Instance` for wich I had to write `from minizinc import Instance` **after** I redefined the default driver.